# In place sorting of a string to find out if there are non-unique characters

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, in-place

Recently I came across a problem that asks to find out the non-unique characters in a string without any additional buffer. I interpreted this problem to be an in-place sort of the characters in the string and then iterating through it in order to track down the non-unique characters.

Another solution that can have O(1) space and O(n^2) run-time is having two 'for' loops going over the string to track down any pairs of characters that are common.

What I need is to sort the string in atleast O(nlogn) time with O(1) space.

Is there a simple/elegant way to do an in-place sort of characters in O(nlgn) with O(1) space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really nice comparison grid of sorting algorithms on wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

**Heapsort** and **Smoothsort** seem to be your obvious winners. Depending on your language you may or may not already have these, though I'm sure in most cases they're probably a library away.

There's a Java impl that at a glance claims to heapsort a set of anything Comparable.
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/heap-sort-implementation-in-java.html

Comment: Heapsort sounds promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

How about, rather than sorting, just scanning the string to find the characters that occur more than once? You can use 256 bits to keep track of which characters occur once, and an additional 256 bits to keep track of the characters that occur at least twice. Total extra memory usage is 512 bits, just 16 32-bit words, and the algorithm runs in linear time, and does not modify the original string.

Comment: ... "without any additional buffer."

Comment: The 512 bits is not a buffer, and it doesn't depend on the length of the string you are processing. It's is O(1) auxiliary memory. The point is, you don't have to sort the characters of the string to accomplish what the OP asks. This method is likely to be significantly faster than any other method for strings that are longer than just a few characters, including the methods in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Shell Sort.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort)